# What is the Fisher information of $X_i$ with $f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi[1+(x-\theta)^2]}$

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid with
$$f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi[1+(x-\theta)^2]}$$
With $x$ real.

I'm trying to find the Fisher information, $I(\theta)$. And a method for finding a 95% confidence interval, can anyone help with this? It would be greatly appreciated!

So far I have found that
$$I(\theta)=2\sum_i^n E \left[ \frac{1-(x_i-\theta)^2}{(1+(x_i-\theta)^2)^2} \right]$$

EDIT:

Here are my workings

$$L(\theta)=\pi^{-n}\prod_i^n \frac{1}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow l(\theta)=-n\operatorname{log}\pi-\sum_i^n\operatorname{log}(1+(x_i-\theta)^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow l'(\theta)= 2\sum_i^n \frac{x_i-\theta}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow -l''(\theta)=2\sum_i^n  \frac{1-(x_i-\theta)^2}{(1+(x_i-\theta)^2)^2}$$

Comment: Backslash (\ ), not slash ( `/` ), for $\LaTeX$ commands.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: sorry about that.. Wrote it on my phone as my Internet is down :(

Comment: Hint: $E_\theta(u(X_i-\theta))$ is independent on $\theta$. Validity check: $I(\theta)=n/\pi$.

Comment: @Didier Piau: thank you! But what do we do about the denominator concerning linearity of the expectation?

Comment: ??? Can you compute $I(\theta)$ when $n=1$?

Comment: @didier piau: No, that is basically what I'm unsure about

Comment: Why not? This is $E(u(X))$ and you know the function $u$ and the distribution of $X$. What is stopping you?

Comment: @Didier Piau: It won't integrate and I can't see errors in my working, is this the right function?

Comment: Can you show your workings which lead to this?

Comment: If it's not integrable, that's not surprising.  If it is, then the sum of the $n$ terms is $n$ times the sum of any one of them, since they're obviously all equal.

Comment: @DidierPiau: Here are my working, sorry for the late reply, my internet is now up again.

Comment: Right. Now you must compute $E((1-(X-\theta)^2)/(1+(X-\theta)^2)^2)$ and you know that the distribution of $X$ has density $f(x)=1/(\pi(1+(x-\theta)^2))$. Thus you are after the expectation of a known function of a random variable with known density. Nothing to stop you here...

Comment: $E \big[ \frac{1-(x_i-\theta)^2}{(1+(x_i-\theta)^2)^2} \big]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-(x_i-\theta)^2}{\pi(1+(x_i-\theta)^2)^3} dx=\frac{1}{4}$ Hmm, ok, thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2158292/321264