# When does a Cramer-Rao lower bound exist?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

From [Cramer Rao lower bound in Cauchy distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158292/cramer-rao-lower-bound-in-cauchy-distribution) in Daniel's reply they mention that such a bound  exist if $\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \theta}$ can be factored.

Is this true? If so what do they mean by factored? If not, is there a way to show that a pdf/pmf doesn't have an unbiased estimator that attains the Cramer-Rao lower bound?

Also in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igQIsYAlKlY
They say that the bound will exist if an unbiased estimator exists. So I only need to show that such an unbiased estimator can exists for a pdf/pmf for the bound to then exist?

Comment: If you follow the proof of the Cramer-Rao inequality (often shown using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality), you will see that equality holds iff $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_{\theta}(x)$ and $T(x)-g(\theta)$ are proportional, where $T$ is an unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$ and $f_{\theta}$ is the parent distribution. That is, assuming $f_{\theta}$ satisfies some regularity conditions, equality holds in the CR inequality iff the following holds for some $k$: $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_{\theta}(x)=k(\theta)(T(x)-g(\theta))$.

Comment: And in case this equality holds, variance of $T$ is said to attain the Cramer-Rao bound for $g(\theta)$.